# Different way to import types definitions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a different way to import type definitions? I just find kinda odd using the regular import for types and the actual module. For example.

```
import { FooType, FooFunction, BooType, BooObject } from './FooFighters';
```

so you can clearly see we have a mix of things here, so I was wondering if there was another way to get one module type definitions other than mixing two things.

Comment: What would the advantage be? What are you hoping to achieve? It might help knowing this so perhaps the question can be answered better or provide alternatives.

Comment: Readability: Easy to distinguish what is a type and what is actual module property, without using any plugin or x. One use case Code Reviews make more sense, where I don't use my nice editor to figure out of is a type.

Comment: This doesn't exist but I was imagining something like  
```
import types { FooType } from './FoofyThings';
```

Comment: left a answer, which I think might be too obvious but mostly has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
import { FooFunction, BooObject } from './FooFighters';

// types
import { FooType, BooType } from './FooFighters';
```

Comment: Yes this works and I thought about it. I was just wondering if there's another way. Thanks